# Object required error. saving ActiveSheet to new workbook

Tags: vba, excel, macros

The purpose of this macro is to select each item in a drop down data validation list, update the sheet and then save the sheet as a new workbook. I get the error "Object required" for the block of code after ws.SaveAs. Can anyone see the problem, as I cannot :/

```
Sub Create_excel_sheets()
Dim strValidationRange As String
Dim rngValidation As Range
Dim rngDepartment As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

strValidationRange = Range("AD5").Validation.Formula1
Set rngValidation = Range(strValidationRange)

For Each rngDepartment In rngValidation.Cells
    Range("AD5").Value = rngDepartment.Value

        ActiveSheet.Calculate
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
        ws.SaveAs _
        FileFormat:=52, _
        Filename:="C:\Test\" & rngDepartment.Value.xlsx, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using the parameters for a [Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.exportasfixedformat.aspx) inside a [Worksheet.SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195820.aspx).

Additionally, the `filename:=` string concatenation is a little wonky with `& rngDepartment.Value.xlsx`. Best to simply leave off the file extension and allow the `FileFormat:=` parameter to supply the correct one. In this case, the [XlFileFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx) you chose (e.g. **52**) is for **xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled** but you seem to be trying to append **.xlsx** on the end.

```
    ws.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, _
              Filename:="C:\Test\" & rngDepartment.Value   '<~~no extension
```

I'm not sure if you were trying to go with .SaveAs or .ExportAsFixedFormat. I've chosen a simple .SaveAs for demonstration

Comment: you're right, i've well and truly mixed up my goals there! Thanks for the help and for the simplification Jeeped :)